# how to load text as html using Html Agility Pack

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

```
<table class="\"matches   \">
<thead>
    <tr class="\"sub-head\">
        <th class="\"day\">
            Day<\/th><th class="\"date\">
                Date<\/th><th class="\"team team-a\">
                    Home team<\/th><th class="\"score-time\">
                        Score\/Time<\/th><th class="\"team team-b\">
                            Away team<\/th><th class="\"events-button button\">
                                &nbsp;<\/th><th class="\"info-button button\">
```

How can i load or parse this text as html then extract it data using HAP? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
string input; 
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input); or htmlDocument.LoadHtml(@input);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack/847051#847051) may help get you started.

Have you got the extra backslashes in there by mistake, or is that how the source HTML document actually looks?